# how to solve gradle faild sync:SSL handshake connection when trying to download recycleview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've tried to download RecycleView in order to use in my project but this error keeps occurring and download fails.

> Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all dependencies for
>   configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.           Could not determine
>   artifacts for androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0            Could not
>   get resource
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.0.0/recyclerview-1.0.0.aar'.
>             Could not HEAD
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.0.0/recyclerview-1.0.0.aar'.
>             Remote host closed connection during handshake          SSL peer shut
>   down incorrectly          Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
>   (12 s 965 ms)

This is the Project Build Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the Module:App build Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aden.adenmarket"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since no one answered my question, I'll post this answer. Maybe it'll help someone who may face an issue like this. I solved this problem by updating Firebase libraries and 
updating these two dependencies to the last version and it worked successfully .

```
//module:app
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.1.0'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
//project Build Graddle
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```